# How to use a dynamic LINQ join extension method for multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, join, dynamic-linq, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to test out a dynamic join extension method as defined [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdba5462-bfc4-4c2c-848f-f5eb6bebc384/dynamically-query-across-multiple-tables) to join two datasets(dataset1 and dataset2) on multiple conditions. My join condition is as shown below

```
    outerSelector = "new ( dataset1.ToBeReconciled as col1, dataset1.TransactionDate as col2)";
innerSelector = "new ( dataset2.ToBeReconciled as col1, dataset2.TransactionDate as col2)";
```

This does not result in any error, but at the same time always returns zero records, even though I have records that match this condition.

Any idea how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start with a simple example, and then try to work through what you have there... I've composed a simple to understand one below..

```
void Main()
{
    var fruits = new List<Fruit>
    {
        new Fruit{ GroceryId = 1,Name = "Apple", ProductId = 1},
        new Fruit{ GroceryId = 1,Name = "Orange", ProductId = 2},
    };

    var groceries = new List<Grocery>
    {
        new Grocery { GroceryId = 1, Name = "Fruits and Vegetables" },
        new Grocery { GroceryId = 2, Name = "Drinks and snacks" },
    };

    var joinedResults = fruits.Join(groceries, // References the groceries declared above,
                                    fruit => fruit.GroceryId,  // Join by GroceryId located on the Fruit
                                    grocery => grocery.GroceryId,  // Join by the GroceryID located on Grocery 
                                    (product, grocery) => new 
                                    {
                                        ProductId = product.ProductId, 
                                        ProductName = product.Name, 
                                        GroceryName = grocery.Name
                                    });
}
public class Fruit
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int GroceryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Grocery
{
    public int GroceryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: The simple one works fine, but my requirement is that I need multiple conditions on join. And join on multiple isn't working.

Comment: So what's preventing you from adding another Join statement to the end of the previous one?

Comment: nothing. It compiles perfectly. But it doesnt work. It always states "enumeration yielded no results" even though there are records that match with the join conditions.